# Regularity of functions approximated by polynomials

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, holder-spaces

I want to ask how to prove the following result:

*Suppose $u\in C(\overline{B_{1}})$, if there exists a universal constant M>0, such that for any $x_{0}\in \overline{B_{1}} $, we have a quadratic polynomial $P_{x_{0}}$ such that*
$$|u(x)-P_{x_{0}}(x)|\leq M|x-x_{0}|^{2+\alpha},\qquad in\ B_{1/4}(x_{0})\cap\overline{B_{1}} $$
*Then, $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{B_{1}})$, and*
$$ [D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}\ \ (\overline{B_{1}})}\leq C_{n}M. $$

The above result states that uniformly pointwise $C^{2,\alpha}$ in $\overline{B_{1}}$ is equivalent to $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{B_{1}})$ in the classical sense. It has background in the theory of elliptic PDE. Caffarelli introduced a method of pointwise approximation by polynomials to prove the interior regularity of solutions to fully nonlinear elliptic equations. Moreover, this method can be used to prove boundary regularity.

Comment: I assume $\overline{B_1}$ is the closed unit ball?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{B_{1}}$ denotes the closed unit ball centered at the origin.

Comment: Well, the idea is that between any two points of $\overline{B_1}$ you can connect them by $\epsilon$-chain of (uniformly bounded) finite length (namely $\lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil+1$), $\epsilon<\frac14$.  Use that and the given estimate to first show $D^2u\in C(\overline{B_1})$ and then control the Holder continuity of $D^2u$.